# update the database when session time out automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to update my database when the session is automatically destroyed in `codeigniter`.

In `application/core` I've created the file `TimeOut.php`.
This is the code:

```
<?php 

class TimeOut extends CI_Session
{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function sess_destroy() {        
         $date = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
        $id = 8;
        $data = array(
      'date_deconnexion' => $date
        );
        $this->db->where('id', $id));
        $this->CI->db->update('historique', $data);

        parent::sess_destroy();
    }

    }

?>
```

But the update is not done, please help.

Comment: Why you are using `$this->CI->db->update('historique',$data)` instead of `this->db->update('historique',$data);`. Why that `CI` extra there??

Comment: probably because session library uses ci instance. So you can't access db without it. Thus db where should also have it.

Comment: i change the code that this this->db->update('historique',$data); but it's the same thing

Comment: please after creating this file should I call it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the following parameter :

$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';

Oliver

Comment: in config.php ?

Comment: if it is that, i do it but nothing

Comment: i find it in the doc: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#custom-drivers